# Laravel Multi BelongsTo RelationShip Merge with Eager Loading

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, polymorphism, laravel-relations

Laravel version:7.0

`reviews` table (Model - Review) has `id`, `product_type`, `product_id`, `rating` columns.

`product_type` can be `service`, `plugin`, `module` and each value has own model `App\Service`, `App\Plugin`, `App\Module`.  I could put `model names` directly in `product_type` but I prefer to use those values.
Here is `Review` model relationship.

```
public function plugin()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Plugin::class, "product_id")->withDefault();
}
public function module()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Module::class, "product_id")->withDefault();
}
public function service()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Service::class, "product_id")->withDefault();
}

public function getItem()
{
   if($this->product_type=='module')
   {
      return $this->module;
   }elseif($this->product_type=='service')
   {
      return $this->service;
   }else {
      return $this->plugin;
   }
}
```

Now I want to get them with eager loading in Review Model as following:

`$reviews  = Review::with("getItem")->get();`

Without Eager loading, I could use `$review->getItem()->name` // this returns name of product.

How can I get them with eager loading?

Answer (score 1):

You could have implemented this easily as a polymorphic relationship. In your Reviews Model, you could do this:

**Model Structure**

**App\Review.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Review extends Model
{
    public function reviewable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Then add reviews() method to your **App\Service**, **App\Plugin** and **App\Module** models

```
public function reviews()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Review', 'reviewable');
}
```

**Table Structure**

You **reviews** table could look like this:

```
reviews
    id - integer
    body - text
    reviewable_id - integer
    reviewable_type - string
```

Note the `reviewable_id` and `reviewable_type` fields. The `reviewable_id` stores the id of the item reviewed and the `reviewable_type` stores the model related to the item.

**Retrieving The Relationship**

You may access the relationships via your models. For example, to access all of the reviews for a service, we can use the reviews dynamic property:

```
$service = App\Service::find(1);

foreach ($service->reviews as $review) {
    //
}
```

You may also retrieve the owner of a polymorphic relation from the polymorphic model by accessing the name of the method that performs the call to morphTo. In your case, that is the reviewable method on the Review model. So, we will access that method as a dynamic property:

```
$review = App\Review::find(1);

$reviewable = $review->reviewable;
```

The reviewable will return the model on the Review model either `Service`, `Plugin` or `Module`

Comment: Thanks, Just changed my table columns. 
However, how to do eager loading?

i tried `$review = Review::with("reviewable")->get()` but it occurs `N+1` query issue. Any suggestion?

Comment: This could help

`Review::with('reviewable')->get()->loadMorph('reviewable', [Service::class => 'service', Plugin::class => 'plugin', Module::class => 'module']);`